# Can I edit the subfiles package to not include new lines after each subfile?

Tags: subfiles

I would like to include a number of subfiles, each of which contains a single sentence, so that together they form a paragraph. However, the subfiles package makes each sentence into a separate paragraph, with a linebreak. Is there any way to edit the subfiles package so that when you include a subfile, it doesn't add a linebreak?

Rough example:

```
\begin{document}
\subfile{s1}\subfile{s2}\subfile{s3}
\end{document}
```

s1:

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
This is my sentence.
\end{document}
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout seems to be caused by line breaks in the subfile. Given the following MWE the output does not contain any extra space or linebreaks:

`subfmain.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{s1}\subfile{s1}\subfile{s1}
\end{document}
```

`s1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[subfmain]{subfiles}\begin{document}This is my sentence.\end{document}
```

Make sure there is also no additional line break at the end of the subfile, i.e., an empty line after `\end{document}`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works

Comment: Is there a way to fix the actual package so that if there are no newlines between `\begin{document}`, the text, and `\end{document}` then there won't be any in the output?

Comment: Do you mean that newlines before `\begin{document}` and after `\end{document}` should be stripped? I don't think that this would be easy - however, for simple files like this it might be easier to just use `\input{subfile}` and not use the `subfiles` package at all.